# Prettify console output of Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am new with Webpack and gradually learning stuff. One thing I don't like or I should say finding it difficult is to interpret the console log message webpack emits when during a build or after that (using webpack cli). Is there any plugin or something that would prettify the output and make it easier to understand like for eg: how gulp outputs stuff like start/end of task, current task being executed and more..

Comment: In webpack there are no "tasks" like in gulp. Webpack simply analyzes your code structure and builds a bundle. In the output you can find all the files it has "emitted" (aka. created). It is quite different then gulp so don't try to migrate things you know from gulp to webpack - it won't work.

Comment: you can use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but here's a package that I use which might help make your output a little less cryptic: [`webpack-messages`](https://github.com/lukeed/webpack-messages).